# How do i render ternary operator(if condition) in jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, conditional-operator

This here is the question

Make a component called Gate that accepts 1 prop called "isOpen". When isOpen is true, make the component render "open", and when isOpen is false, make it render "closed". Hint: you can do conditional logic inside JSX with the ternary (question mark, ?) operator, inside single braces, like this: {speed > 80 ? "danger!" : "probably fine"} (which evaluates to "danger!" if speed is over 80, and "probably fine" otherwise).

while this is the code :

````
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const Gate=({isOpen})=> (
  <div>
   { isOpen }
  </div>
)

ReactDOM.render(<Gate {isOpen?<h1>hello</h1>:<h1>not hello</h1>} />, document.querySelector('#root'));```
````

Comment: my code isnt working as expected, i think i'm doing something wrongly but i dont really know what that is.

Answer (score 2):

The `isOpen` value is in the `Gate` component, so the condition would go in the rendering within that component:

```
const Gate=({isOpen})=> (
  <div>
    { isOpen ? <h1>hello</h1> : <h1>not hello</h1> }
  </div>
)
```

Then when using the component you would pass a *value* for that prop:

```
<Gate isOpen={true} />
```

---

You *can* otherwise pass the element to display and put the condition outside the component.  For example, taking your original `Gate` component:

```
const Gate=({isOpen})=> (
  <div>
    { isOpen }
  </div>
)
```

In this case the component isn't expecting a condition as a prop, it's expecting something to render.  You can conditionally pass it something to render.  *But* you would need that condition available where you use it.  For example, the structure would be like this:

```
<Gate isOpen={true ? <h1>hello</h1> : <h1>not hello</h1>} />
```

Clearly this is *always* `true`, but in this structure you'd simply replace `true` with whatever your dynamic condition is.

In either case, `isOpen` is a prop being passed to the `Gate` component.

Comment: waw thanks.This is actually my first time on stack and i've been looking for answers for dayds now thanks

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is using ternary operator in `Gate` compoent render `open` or `closed` as per the value of `isOpen` as:

[`CODESANDBOX LINK`](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-johnson-s8vsze?file=/src/App.js)

```
const Gate = ({ isOpen }) => <div>{isOpen ? "open" : "closed"}</div>;
```

If you want to render in `H1` then you can do as:

```
const Gate2 = ({ isOpen }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{isOpen ? "open" : "closed"}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
```